# Inbox com hash (#) não está rolando até o comentário na página da "eleição"

Tags: bug, eleição

Toda vez que chega um comentário e eu clico nele, por exemplo:

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/1#post-141024

Deveria "rolar" a página até o local, mas isto não ocorre.

Comment: Desisti de tentar achar a causa quando vi que a lista de candidaturas é na verdade uma grande tabela.

Comment: É, pode ser.  Mas não achei nada nessa página com esse id `141009`, o comentário foi excluído?

Comment: Percebi esse bug tb

Comment: Provavelmente por o *link* estar errado, **`post-{id}`** pelo que eu vi é usado somente nas candidaturas. Nos comentários é usado **`comment-{id}`**: [exemplo - #comment-140970](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/1#comment-140970). Se esse *link* apontava para um comentário, seria `comment-141024` não!?

Comment: @re22 parece que você está correto, o bug é no link gerado pelo inbox então.

Comment: Esse *link* apontava pra candidatura do SneepS NinjA? Vi que ele [removeu](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/election?1#comment-140713).

Comment: @re22 é o ultimo comentário do candidato Patrick Maciel em resposta para mim. Eu tentei trocar por `comment-` conforme mostra `<tr id="comment-141024" class="comment ">`, mas não funcionou, talvez `<tr>` no Webkit/Blink não suporte ID.

Comment: Pior que não, tentei aqui (Firefox) e também não funcionou. Eu pensei que os comentários ficavam "escondidos", mas pelo que eu vi eles não existem na página até que seja clicado naquele *mostrar mais **x** comentários*. Se clicar para exibir todos os comentários e tentar acessar [o link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/1#comment-141024), vai funcionar ok. *Houston, we have a bug...*

Comment: @re22 Realmente funciona, o problema é mesmo com a ação pelo "inbox" deveria exibir o comentário oculto, como é nos comentários em postagens. Geralmente exibe um link com `?` ao invés de `#` e auto-carrega a mensagem, não me lembro ao certo. Quem sabe na próxima eleição irá funcionar normalmente :)